# Misunderstanding the cycle tag in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, cycle

I am not sure whether I have discovered a bug, have my system misconfigured, or am just misunderstanding the {% cycle %} template tag in Django.

The manual provides the following sample code:

```
{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' as rowcolors silent %}{# no value here #}
{% for o in some_list %}
    <tr class="{% cycle rowcolors %}">{# first value will be "row1" #}
        ...
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

It clearly says that the first cycle declaration will output nothing, and the subsequent call will be the first iteration.

I am having the following issues:  firstly, the second call outputs 'row2', which would be expected on the second call.  Secondly, the subsequent {% cycle rowcolors %} calls don't output anything either!

Am I completely misunderstanding something, or does the tag not work as specified?

Comment: Couldn't find your sample code in the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle). Do you have a link?

Comment: I was mistaken, I thought I got the sample from the docs but it was actually from the code itself.  Lines 534-539, here:  https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaulttags.py

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the code is the cycle function's docstring is different from the code example in [the actual documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle). You should be using `{{ rowcolors }}` to display the cycled text.

> Secondly, the subsequent {% cycle rowcolors %} calls don't output anything either!

From the documentation:

> When the silent keyword is used on a cycle definition, the silence automatically applies to all subsequent uses of the cycle tag. In, the following template would output nothing, even though the second call to {% cycle %} doesn't specify silent:

The code example that follows that paragraph seems to be similar to your current issue.

Comment: So, it seems they have updated the docstring before they have updated the code?  I would hate to think the converse were true, that the functionality in the docstring is how the tag *used* to work, because the docstring behavior is much more desirable.

Comment: As far I can tell, the documentation and code were updated (to fix https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15570), but the docstring was not. I filed a ticket (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18933) on the Django bug tracker and submitted a pull request to have this fixed.